# Display SQL-query in HTML?

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a simple query showing 7 numbers, all from the same column.

Example:

```
93000
12365
3500
3125
2963
31
9
```

How do I display those results on an HTML-page? I just want all the numbers to be displayed like a list, under each other.

Comment: use <li> tags inside a for loop which prints these numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can put the result of that column in an array by using explode function with a space seperator, and  in html you can append the result to an unordered list using JQuery's for in loop or forEach loop.

Comment: jQuery? `PHP` echo isn't enough?

Comment: @ Nick R Why create unnecessary pressure on the server side if something can be achieved on client side?  Besides you need JQuery if Ajax is applied.

Comment: But it wouldn't be, it's already queried the database and got the result, echoing out 7 numbers isn't really putting pressure on the server. Also if you're not already including jQuery, that's another 80KB+ to add to the page load.

Comment: When it comes into live project it won't be just 7 number echoing, it is always recomended to do this kind of stuff using client side.

Comment: Recommended? Don't think I've read that. Anyway - `Besides you need JQuery if Ajax is applied` - no you don't, You could use the `XMLHttpRequest` JS object.